# Addition of third column till specific row of second column by using perl

Tags: perl

i have an input like below:

```
atom 1 23
atom 1 13
atom 1 22
atom 1 24
atom 2 99
atom 2 98
atom 2 21
atom 3 15
atom 3 20
atom 4 19
atom 5 11
```

and i want to total third column but it should report as if it reads 1 in second column it should give total of all 1's value in third column. similarly, than in second column if it is 2 it should give total of 2's value in third column. similarly, then in second column if it is three then it should give total of three in third column. Likewise till end of file. plz help me out on this..

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
while (<>) {
    my @elems = split;
    $hash{ $elems[1] } += $elems[2];
}

print "atom $_ $hash{$_}\n" for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash;
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Output on your dataset:

```
atom 1 82
atom 2 218
atom 3 35
atom 4 19
atom 5 11
```